# Stored procedure not detecting change in database in Blazor server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net

Here I have a stored procedure `dbo.sp_GetChatMessages` which returns all columns that is `DualMessageId,SenderName,ReceiverName,MessageBody,SendOn,IsSeen` column value from table `DualMessage`.

Now the problem is that if I make any changes to any of the column of `DualMessage` table and then call the procedure from my service, then the procedure returns same old the value which are before making any changes, that is it does not return that new changed value but running the same procedure in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) works fine and gives the changed value.

Below is how I call my procedure in service

```
public class MainService
{
    public BlazorDBContext db = new BlazorDBContext();
    public List<DualMessage> GetAllChatMessagesToDisplay(string loggedinUserName)
    {
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@loggedInUserName", loggedinUserName);
        var messagesList = db.DualMessage.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.sp_GetChatMessages @loggedInUserName", param1).ToList();
        return messagesList;
    }
}
```

Below is stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetChatMessages] (@loggedInUserName nvarchar(500))
AS
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DualMessageId, SenderName, ReceiverName, MessageBody, SendOn, IsSeen,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY 
                concat(@loggedInUserName, CASE WHEN senderName =@loggedInUserName 
                                      THEN receiverName 
                                      ELSE senderName END ) 
            ORDER BY sendOn DESC ) AS rn
    FROM DualMessage 
    WHERE senderName=@loggedInUserName 
          OR receiverName=@loggedInUserName)  as msg 
WHERE 
msg.rn=1 
ORDER BY DualMessageId DESC;
```

Comment: Usually this is because you are not connecting to the database you think you are. Verify the connection

Comment: Or using an older transaction (or not committing the transaction that made the change).

Comment: You do not need @loggedInUserName in the FromSQLRaw since it is already in the parameter.

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working on day (after an update/upgrade). [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: @Larnu Removing sp_ prefix doesnot give the updated value

Comment: I never said it would, @sudipchand ?

Comment: Too many guesses here. AFAIK Blazor service lifetime is long, so is the injected DbContext, hence most likely you are experiencing EFC context tracking (caching) behavior. Try using [No Tracking query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)